# CSS Selectors - Search for unique value in a child(ren)

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

I'm writing selenium tests for a web application. The application uses dynamically built forms which means I have a lot of non-unique elements to try and traverse (#ids are scarce, or very top level). These forms can also change depending on set up (position of elements can be different, so nth-child is unreliable).

There are some fields that I want to find by unqiue class names which these posses, however they are burried inside non-unique elements. I need a way to locate these elements by their unique values (which are not #ids) so their position on the form will not affect selenium finding them. I not sure how to do this though.

Hopefully this explains the scenario:

```
<Some non-unqiue Div>
  <child>
    <child>
      <unique value 1>
<Some non-unqiue Div>
  <child>
    <child>
     <unique value 2>
<Some non-unqiue Div>
  <child>
    <child>
      <unique value I WANT THIS ONE>
<Some non-unqiue Div>
  <child>
    <child>
      <unique value 4>
```

You can see here that the element I want has a unique value that I want to match on. However, I cant use nth-child(3) to navigate to its parents as the order they can appear in may vary. For example, in a different scenario it may be nth-child(2).

So a selector which might work for above might look like:

```
Some.nth-child(3) > child > child > [unique*=\"I WANT THIS ONE\"]
```

However, in another scenario this the top parent might be nth-child(2) so this would no longer work.

Is there any Css selector magic I can employ to make sure I can always find this element by its unique value, regardless of where in the list its parents appear?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try anything? Share your code

Comment: Not at the moment, I don't really know how to approach this at all. I know how I can select the element I'm after once I get to its level, but its reversing through the parents that I'm stuck with

Comment: What does "unique value" translate to in the HTML...is it  a class, attrriubute or what?

Comment: Its a class name. So for example one might have a class "aw-ml" which contains my unique value:

div > div > div > [aw-ml*=\"myValue\"]

Comment: Updated OP with a little more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my word. I think I've stumbled across the answer and it's something I never even thought of.

So in my Css selectors I've always used ">" to seperate my elements, I always just thought this was the syntax to separate them. However, just read that ">" is for direct children of the previous element!

If you use a space instead of ">" then it searches the entire tree beneath that element for the value you are looking for! I'm somewhat self taught in automation and I can't believe I didnt realise this was a thing.

Just tried a selector similar to "#myId [value="my value"]" using a space to separate the two elements and it searched the whole tree and landed correctly on my element.

Comment: Here are some CSS selector references that have helped me: [Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors), [W3C Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview), and [Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

If I catch the problem in a right way, here are the selectors you are looking for:

```
'element/id/class:contains("I WANT THIS ONE")'
```

or for input type:

```
'element/id/class[value="I WANT THIS ONE"]'
```

for example:

```
'input[value="I WANT THIS ONE"]'
```

or for element with innerHTML:

```
'div:contains("I WANT THIS ONE")'
```

or for both of them:

```
'input[value="I WANT THIS ONE"],div:contains("I WANT THIS ONE")'
```

Is it usable for you?

Comment: Selecting the final element based on its value is fine (ive updated the OP to be a bit more clear). Its traversing the tree to reach the point where I can select it that I'm having trouble with. Thanks for the detailed reply though!